# google sheets script regarding sending emails

Tags: email, google-sheets, automation

I'd presume this would be an easy solve but I've been unable to find a solution anywhere online.

I'm trying to send automated emails when I run a script. The problem is it will send one email for every row (multiple emails to the same person) instead of sending one email with every row/column included in that one email.

The second issue is I want to send to more than one recipient. In my sheet, I want to send the data in B2:F3 to the first email address and then I want to send B4:F5 to the second email provided.

Thank you for your help. - Jared

Here's my script:

```
function sendEmails() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("sheet1"));
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("A2:m8");
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var rowData = data[i];
    var emailAddress = rowData[0];
    var city = rowData[11];
    var dimension = rowData[1];
    var product = rowData[2];
    var tally = rowData[3];
    var price = rowData[5];
    var ship = rowData[5];
    var message = city + '\n\n' + dimension + ' ' + product + ' ' + tally + ' ' + price + ' ' + ship;
    var subject = 'PFP Lumber';
   MailApp.sendEmail("emailaddress1@blank.com",
                   "PFP Lumber",
                   message);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your shared sample sheet and script, there are some questions.

- It seems that `price` and `ship` are `rowData[5]`.

  - `price` and `ship` are `rowData[4]` and `rowData[5]`, respectively?
- It seems that `rowData[11]` is `Phone`.

  - Is this `rowData[6]`?

If `price`, `ship` and `Phone` are `rowData[4]`, `rowData[5]` and `rowData[6]`, respectively, you want to send the following emails.

> Mail 1 :
>   mailaddress: emailaddress1@blank.com
>
> message: Gulfport desc1 1 1 1 1, Gulfport desc2 2 2 2 2
>
> Mail 2 :
>   mailaddress: emailaddress2@blank.com
>
> message: Gulfport desc3 3 3 3 3, Gulfport desc4 4 4 4 4

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? I think that there are several answers for your situation, so please think of this as one of them.

#### Modification points :

- Retrieve email address and messages.

  - When new email address was NOT found at column A, the message is added.
  - When new email address was found at column A, the email is separated.

#### Modified script :

```
function sendEmails() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("sheet1"));
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("A2:m8");
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  // Modified
  var temp = [];
  var emailAddress, dimension, product, tally, price, ship, city;
  for (var i in data) {
    [emailAddress, dimension, product, tally, price, ship, city] = data[i];
    var message = city + '\n\n' + dimension + ' ' + product + ' ' + tally + ' ' + price + ' ' + ship;
    if (emailAddress || !dimension) {
      if (temp.length > 0) {
        MailApp.sendEmail(temp[0], "PFP Lumber", temp.slice(1,temp.length).join("\n"));
        var temp = [];
      }
      temp.push(emailAddress, message);
      if (!dimension) break;
    } else {
      temp.push(message);
    }
  }
}
```

#### Note :

- Several messages for one mail address is separated by `\n`.
- Because I'm not sure the variables for each columns that you want to use, please modify them if the variables of my modified script is difference from you want.
- In this modified script, after the rows that `Dimension` of column B is empty, I recognized that there are no emails you want to send.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

### Edit :

When you want to add a signature, how about this script?

```
function sendEmails() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("sheet1"));
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("A2:m8");
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  var temp = [];
  var emailAddress, dimension, product, tally, price, ship, city;
  var signature = "\n---\nsample signature";
  for (var i in data) {
    [emailAddress, dimension, product, tally, price, ship, city] = data[i];
    var message = city + '\n\n' + dimension + ' ' + product + ' ' + tally + ' ' + price + ' ' + ship;
    if (emailAddress || !dimension) {
      if (temp.length > 0) {
        MailApp.sendEmail(temp[0], "PFP Lumber", temp.slice(1,temp.length).join("\n") + signature);
        var temp = [];
      }
      temp.push(emailAddress, message);
      if (!dimension) break;
    } else {
      temp.push(message);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Amazing...It works like a charm. I'm trying to figure out how you did that but don't know enough about to java to figure it out. Thank you so much. Have you sent emails this way before? Do you by chance know how to include your gmail signature?

Comment: No problem! I really appreciate your help. Where's the accept button? I can't try the edited script at the moment because I sent to many emails through trial and error on my own and went over my gmail limit on the day haha

Comment: @Ichi Futures Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was solved.

Comment: @Ichi Futures I'm really sorry. I cannot understand your current situation from your comment. So although I'm not sure whether this is the solution for your situation, please try to [install a trigger for the function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable). If this was not the solution, can you post it by the detail information as a new post? By this, we will be able to think of the solution. I'm sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: your English is great! I'm needing what I needed before. For some reason it's not working now with my final database (posted in my previous message). If you click on the link you can access my spreadsheet and script.  I'll create a new post if needed...

Comment: @Ichi Futures In order to understand your situation, can you post it with the detail information as a new question? By this, many users including me will be able to think of your solution. I'm sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Ichi Futures Thank you. I would like to confirm it.

Comment: did you see my new post?

Comment: @Ichi Futures I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I couldn't notice it.

Comment: @Ichi Futures I saw it. It seems that the answer has already been posted to the comment.

Comment: @tankaike your solutions are easier to understand. I don't really know what to do with that users response :/

Comment: @Ichi Futures Thank you for your reply. If you cannot understand the comments of the user who commented to your question, can you ask them to the user. If you cannot easily understand the user's comment, you can also ask the user about the detail. Don't worry. I think that the user will answer for your question.

Comment: I'll add comments in there but maybe you can tell me why the code no longer sends one email for multiple rows of data? I'm not sure what happened.